# Moodle docker installation issue mysql_full_unicode_support#File_format and mysql_full_unicode_support#Large_prefix

Tags: docker, kubernetes, moodle

Moodle installation error in docker and kubernetes

mysql_full_unicode_support#File_format and mysql_full_unicode_support#Large_prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have access to under lying resources and pod or docker container

or

if you have access to mysql server

simply you have to run in mysql

```
mysql > set Global innodb_file_format = Barracuda
mysql > set Global innodb_file_per_table = 1
mysql > set Global innodb_large_prefix = "ON"
```